# Laravel pass url parameter to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My current url I'm on is *localhost/test/1*

When I click on save button, it's going to call a rest service *test/{id}/createNewTest*. How do I get the {id} in the controller? Right now it's getting nothing.

### **Routes**

```
Route::post('test/{id}/createNewTest', 'TestController@createNewTest');
```

### **Controller**

```
public function createNewTest() {
   $id = Request::input('id');
}
```

the $id is suppose to be 1 here, but it's getting nothing

Answer (score 1):

Route parameters are passed into the controller via method parameters, not as request input:

```
public function createNewTest($id) {
    var_dump($id); // from method parameter, not Request::input()
}
```

Comment: @ilearn Your route definition looks fine.  Are you sure you didn't POST to `test/0/createNewTest`?

Comment: hmm. In the database, it's posted as 0, but when I dumped $id out, it's show {id}. Also, the rest url is passed to an $.ajax(type: 'POST', url: test/{id}/createNewTest, data: postParam). Maybe there's something wrong in the ajax?

Comment: @ilearn whatever code you have generating that ajax request is not replacing {id} with the id value.  That needs to be fixed.